# Slab based commission calculation in Power Bi DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, categories, percentage, slab

I need to calculate slab based commission in Power BI.
Below is a sample of the commission table.

The percentage commission only applies to the amount that is considered in that category. So for a sale of $35000 the commission would be calculated by:

**$25000 * 0,0228 = $570**

**$10000 * 0,0220 = $220**

**Total commission = $790**

Seems simple, but can't figure out how to calculate this using a DAX formula. Any suggestions?

| Category | Lower | upper | commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0-25000 | 0 | 25000 | 2,28 |
| 25000,01-100000 | 25000,01 | 100000 | 2,20 |
| 10000,01-200000 | 200000,01 | 200000 | 2,32 |